# Java ASM visitMethodInsn parameters?

Tags: java, stack, java-bytecode-asm, visitor-pattern, invocation

I'm trying to understand how Java's ObjectWeb ASM library (framework?) works by a combination of reading the documentation and looking at example code. I'm slowly getting the idea behind it, but I've found a bit of example code that I'm just not understanding, so I hope someone here can explain it to me.

The code takes `mv`, a MethodVisitor obtained from a ClassWriter's `visitMethod` method, and starts manipulating the method like this:

```
    mv.visitCode();
    String methodSignature = "(L" + worldClass + ";IIIL" + blockClass + ";)V";

    Label l0 = new Label();
    mv.visitLabel(l0);
    mv.visitLineNumber(81, l0);
    mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);
    mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 2);
    mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 3);
    mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 4);
    mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "com/olafski/fastleafdecay/FldHandler", "handleLeafDecay", methodSignature);
```

There's more to it, of course, but this is the part I don't understand. As you can see from the method signature, it takes 5 arguments: a World class, three integers, and a Block class (and yes, those variables in the signature string do hold the proper FQNs for those classes). Yet before the new method invocation is visited, only **four** parameters are pushed onto the stack (plus the reference to `this`). So where is it getting the fifth parameter from?

Answer (score 1):

There are five parameters:

Because `handleLeafDecay` is a static method (`INVOKESTATIC` operand is used to call it), the reference to `this` is not pushed on stack before method call. However, the reference to `this` is used as the fifth parameter.

So the generated bytecode would be equivalent to this code:

```
public void generatedMethod(World wolrd, int i1, int i2, int i3, Block block) {
    FldHandler.handleLeafDecay(wolrd, i1, i2, i3, this);
    // ...
}
```

That means this method is inside `Block` class or it's derivatives. Also the `block` parameter is unused.